# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.IbatisException

Tags: java, mybatis

This is the first time I am working on Mybatis. I am trying to create a connection but getting following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.IbatisException:    
    ### Error building SqlSession.
    ### The error may exist in SQL Mapper Configuration
    ### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 16; Document root element "configuration", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
        at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:8)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:32)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:15)
        at Database_and_tables.mybatisInsert.main(mybatisInsert.java:19)
    Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 16; Document root element "configuration", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
        at org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.createDocument(XPathParser.java:136)
        at org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.<init>(XPathParser.java:32)
        at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.<init>(XMLConfigBuilder.java:47)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:28)
        ... 2 more
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 16; Document root element "configuration", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(XMLDTDValidator.java:1599)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1877)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:742)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1363)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1292)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3138)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:348)
        at `enter code here`org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.createDocument(XPathParser.java:134)
        ... 5 more
```

**mybatisSelect.java**

```
    package Database_and_tables;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.Reader;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources;
    import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession;
    import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
    import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder;

    public class mybatisSelect { 

       public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

          Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("SqlMapConfig.xml");

          SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);       
          SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();


          List<Borrower> borrower = session.selectList("Borrower.getAll");

          for(Borrower st : borrower ){       
             System.out.println(st.getCUSTOMER_NAME());
             System.out.println(st.getLOAN_NUMBER());

          }  

          System.out.println(" successfully");
          session.commit();
          session.close();
       }   
    }
```

**Borrower.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace = "resources/Borrower">   
   <resultMap id = "result" type = "Borrower">
      <result property = "CUSTOMER_NAME"/>  
      <result property = "LOAN_NUMBER" />    
   </resultMap>

   <select id = "getAll" resultMap = "result">
      SELECT * FROM Borrower; 
   </select>

   <select id = "getById" parameterType = "int" resultMap = "result">
      SELECT * FROM Borrower WHERE LOAN_NUMBER = !#{LOAN_NUMBER};
   </select>
</mapper>
```

**Borrower.Java**

```
package Database_and_tables;

public class Borrower {
           private String CUSTOMER_NAME;
           private String LOAN_NUMBER;

        /*   public Borrower( String CUSTOMER_NAME, String LOAN_NUMBER) {
                  super();
                  this.CUSTOMER_NAME = CUSTOMER_NAME;
                  this.LOAN_NUMBER = LOAN_NUMBER;

               }*/

           //getters setters
        public String getCUSTOMER_NAME() {
            return CUSTOMER_NAME;
        }
        public void setCUSTOMER_NAME(String cUSTOMER_NAME) {
            CUSTOMER_NAME = cUSTOMER_NAME;
        }
        public String getLOAN_NUMBER() {
            return LOAN_NUMBER;
        }
        public void setLOAN_NUMBER(String lOAN_NUMBER) {
            LOAN_NUMBER = lOAN_NUMBER;
        }
    [enter image description here][1]
```

**SqlMapConfig.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <environments default = "development">
      <environment id = "development">
         <transactionManager type = "JDBC"/> 

         <dataSource type = "POOLED">
            <property name = "driver" value = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name = "url" value = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:pavan2531"/>
            <property name = "username" value = "c##pavan"/>
            <property name = "password" value = "pavan"/>
         </dataSource>   

      </environment>
   </environments>

   <mappers>
      <mapper resource = "Borrower.xml"/>
   </mappers>

</configuration>
```

Screenshot

[image]

Can some one please help me with this error?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Try adding your code that shows that error so we can see in which part of your code went wrong.

Comment: Can you include your `mybatis-config.xml` also?

Comment: I included at the bottom. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You have an error in your XML mappings file; it's telling you the line number, column number and XML element where the error lies.

Post your XML config file in order to help you (also for reference in future searches for this question).

**UPDATE**

Can you include this DTD declaration and see what happens?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
```

Also, make sure you don't have any hidden character(s).

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: After updating DTD in configuration file I am getting following error   Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource resources/Borrower.xml  I think this is some path issue.

Comment: I think is the `namespace` attribute in your `Borrower.xml`; try using the package name for that class: `<mapper namespace="Database_and_tables.Borrower">`.